# Problems with Drupal login through external php file

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7

I want to login to drupal through an external php file.

My testserver is located at http://develop.dev, the following login script is in a subfolder in the same domain.

```
 /*
 * testlogin.php   
 * 
 */

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs_develop');
include_once '../includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

global $user;
//just a test -> login as admin
$uid = 1;

$login_array = array ('name' => $user->name);
user_login_finalize($login_array);

echo "user is logged in? ".user_is_logged_in();
```

This procedure seems to work. I’m logged in as user admin and can execute drupal functions.

However, when I then visit http://develop.dev within the same webbrowser I see that I’m not logged in. Is this a problem with the drupal session? What is my mistake?

Thank you for any hint, rhodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to load the user 1 first and then assign it back to global $user.

```
$uid = 1;
$account = user_load($uid);
global $user;
$user = $account;
$login_array = array ('name' => $user->name);
user_login_finalize($login_array);
```